# Dynamically created combo boxes very slow

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a panel that I am adding user controls that contains a combo box, among other things (label, text box, buttons).  They user controls are long and skinny, and added one after another down the panel.  The problem is whenever I put anything (about 10..15 items) in the combo box, the update time is painfully slow.  I've tried suspend layout and resume layout on the panel, but that does nothing.

Google searching and trying hasn't yielded anything that works.  I've tried putting all my user controls in an array and then adding them all at once with MyPanel.AddRange.  I tried using AddRange in adding the items to the combo box.  None of this has helped.  When I leave the combo box empty, (leaving everything except the final AddRange as setting SelectionIndex), the panel draws fast, so I know it is not my code itself taking the time.  Calling MyPanel.suspendLayout and MyPanel.ResumeLayout makes no difference.

I am using Winforms, not WPF.

Comment: Provide the code you're using to generate your controls. It will be easier to locate the problem with that.

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple test case and can't get it to misbehave.  There must be something else.  Maybe the table layout panel is doing it.  I'll do a little more investigating to see if I can get an isolated reproduction of the problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem was that I was RDP'ed in.  Tomorrow at work, I'll try the same thing on the computer without being remoted in.  Long story why I am using RDP, and not VB.NET on my desk machine (still LAN, though).

Comment: Back at work.  It is definitely an RDP issue.  For the most part, remoting over LAN is unnoticeable, but with dynamically generated combo boxes, it was painfully slow, yet snappy when not remoted in.